# Cómo dar formato científico a números

Tags: java

Quisiera que en Java, me imprimiera valores con una terminacion científica mas reducida Ejem: 0.0003213265675676 = 3.213265675676E-4.

Lo intento de forma normal pero me da como 10 ó 12 dígitos después del punto, y quisiera 2 ó 4 para que quedara ejem: 3.4E-4 pero no sé cómo hacerlo, intenté de esta forma pero se termina perdiendo:

```
   System.out.println("Num: ");
   double z=leer.nextDouble();
   double x=z;
   z=Math.abs(z);
   z=Math.log10(z);
   z=Math.floor(z);

   System.out.println(""+z);
   System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", x)+" E"+z);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.format()` da alguna ayuda para convertir números a `String` pero no es un método muy especializado, así que es bastante limitado.

Lo mejor es usar [java.text.DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) que ofrece muchas más opciones. En concreto, lo que quieres funcionaría

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
System.out.println(df.format(3.14159258));
```

Puedes [probarlo aquí](https://ideone.com/NaVz74)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!